# Importing another project to my JSFProject

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf

I got this project with JSF where i'm dealing with managed beans. the only problem is that my beans are in another project that i created earlier i want these beans to be seen in my current project. i've tried to export my earlier project to a JAR file and added it to my library but i don't know if my tables (DATABASE & DAO) will be created in this project.
Please if anyone can help me or suggest another alternative of working it would be very helpfull. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With eclipse you can configure your dependent projects. Do a right click on your project and check your project settings.

Other options are using tools like maven for dependency management. However this is probably overkill for you.

For web applications you can place your dependent libraries in `WEB-INF/lib`.

I'd recommend to use the eclipse project configuration though as you don't want to update the jar after every change.